# project riff error java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create functions

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, minikube

I am using a very simple project-riff with minkube running on my mac laptop. It has worked once in the past. After making few changes to the function, I am unable to create bean for Function. I get following stacktrace in the minkube pod that tries to execute the function.

Will appreciate any help. Not sure, what am I doing wrong. I have a simple node.js function the computes the square of a number. That seems to work fine.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FunctionExecutorApplication {    

    @Bean
    Function<Flux<String>,Flux<String>> uppercase(){
        return influx ->
        influx.map(String::toUpperCase);
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FunctionExecutorApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The poject url is
https://github.com/jaysara/FunctionExecutor

Here is the stacktrace that I see in the minikube logs for where pod is trying to initialize the function.

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at io.projectriff.invoker.ContextRunner$1.run(ContextRunner.java:66)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create functions
    at io.projectriff.invoker.FunctionConfiguration.init(FunctionConfiguration.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create bean for: uppercase
    at io.projectriff.invoker.FunctionConfiguration$BeanCreator.create(FunctionConfiguration.java:282)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at io.projectriff.invoker.FunctionConfiguration.init(FunctionConfiguration.java:130)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: You should include the code to reproduce in the question itself, not in an external link.